# floating action button animation works only on first click

Tags: android, animation, floating-action-button

fab antimation only work on first time I click. after that when I click on the button, on click listener works and fab show but without animation. I am creating it on fragment. `mAddFab` is the main button to show other fab's and `mRequestFab`, `mDonateFab` are the buttons which shows after `mAddFab` button clicked. Tell me if animation file needed

```
 public class NameFragment extends Fragment {
    
        private FloatingActionButton mAddFab, mRequestFab, mDonateFab;
    
        private Animation mFabOpenAnim, mFabCloseAnim, rotateOpen, rotateClose;
    
        private boolean isOpen;
        private Context context;
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            context = getContext();
    
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    
            mFabOpenAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fab_open_anim);
            mFabCloseAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fab_close_anim);
            rotateOpen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.rotate_open_anim);
            rotateClose = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.rotate_close_anim);
    
            isOpen = false;
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plasma, container, false);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    
            mAddFab = view.findViewById(R.id.addbtn);
            mRequestFab = view.findViewById(R.id.requestbtn);
            mDonateFab = view.findViewById(R.id.donatebtn);
    
            mAddFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    
                    if(isOpen){
                        mAddFab.setAnimation(rotateClose);
                        mRequestFab.setAnimation(mFabCloseAnim);
                        mDonateFab.setAnimation(mFabCloseAnim);
    
    
                        mRequestFab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mDonateFab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    
                        isOpen = false;
                    } else {
                        mAddFab.setAnimation(rotateOpen);
                        mDonateFab.setAnimation(mFabOpenAnim);
                        mRequestFab.setAnimation(mFabOpenAnim);
    
                        mDonateFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mRequestFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    
                        isOpen = true;
                    }
    
                }
            });
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. the problem was with the function that I have used to do the animation which is `setAnimation()` and I have changed it with `startAnimation()`.Main differences between both the functions are-

SetAnimation-

when the view is added to the viewGroup, animation will be called and when the view has been added, the animation will not be called

StartAnimation-

animation will be called all the time even though the view has been added.